# UiView.animateWithDuration Not Animating Swift3

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3

I am trying to animate all view outlets from bottom using below code (The outlets should come from bottom and fill the view within 1 seconds). However, it doesn't animate and everything is immediately shown no matter how much time I put. I noticed following:

- Duration is not respected
- Not even delay is respected
- Animation is not happening. Component is immediately shown

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  ```
      super.viewDidAppear(animated);
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

      self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
      self.imageView.frame.origin.y = 1024;
      self.view.setNeedsLayout();
  })
  ```

Comment: 1. didn’t work , 2. 1-2 seconds , 3. I already know that . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue myself.

```
super.viewDidAppear(animated);

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.imageView.frame.origin.y = 1024;
        self.view.setNeedsLayout();
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `self.imageView.frame.origin.y = 1024;`, and set  `self.topConstraint.constant = 1024;` before animation block